# how to solve query issue in server which is running properly in localhost?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have written a query to get data between current date & previous date, day before yesterday & so on.

My sql query is

```
select *
from details
where datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
```

interval number is changes dynamically from 1 to 20

This query is working properly in localhost's phpmyadmin, but when i tried the same query in server's phpmyadmin result is not coming.

Don't know what is the problem here. 
Please help me with this.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: On which server you have deployed your project? is it Linux based Ubuntu ?

Comment: database is mysql,    result will be all the data between those to date difference

Comment: It is  Linux Server

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the server is configured differently when it comes to keywords and that using the type `DATETIME` as a column name is not allowed on the server, try quoting it in your query

```
select *
from details
where ´datetime´ BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Comment: $this->db->where('datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL "'.$interval.'" DAY) AND NOW()') this is how i used in codeigniter active records

Comment: @AshKenton I am not sure what you mean, did you understand that it is datetime that needs to be quoted?

Comment: datetime field name has to be quoted?

Comment: @AshKenton, yes that is my guess (or renamed to something that isn't a reserved word)